# Delay job with lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda, delayed-job

I need to send 2 actions to the background. I could write :

```
myobject.delay.action1
myobject.delay.action2
```

But I can't be sure `action2` starts **after** `action1` finished, can I?

So instead, I could create a method on the fly.

```
def action1and2
  myobject.action1
  myobject.action2
end

myobject.delay.action1and2
```

but it feels stupid to create a named function to do this meaningless group, doesn't it?

So instead, inspired by JS, I thought of writing a lambda:

```
-> {
  myobject.action1
  myobject.action2
}
```

Can I delay such function? Or is there an alternative to my situation?

Comment: if action2 needs to come after action1, then surely they are in some way linked and can be given a meaningful name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myobject.delay.instance_eval { action1; action2 }
```

Comment: How would one pass delayed_job params to this? Like `run_at`?

Comment: `myobject.delay(run_at: Date.tomorrow).instance_eval { ... }`

Comment: myobject.delay.instance_eval { action1; action2 } is equivalent of

Comment: ````myobject.delay.action1;
     myobject.delay.action2````

Answer (score 0):

Creating the method `action1and2` is the correct way.

`action1and2` will be called by the "background process" and it will run in single thread as you expected.

> Can I delay such function?

No, you can't.
Check `delay` function and you will find there is no magic but it will serialize your function call with params, deserialize it in the job process and run it.
Your inline function can not be serialized.